# Scrollable content - angular-calendar

Tags: angular, scroll, calendar, scrollbar, angular-calendar

I'm trying to implement mattlewis92's angular calendar (https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar) and I can't figure out what i need to make views scrollable.

I need help implementing **overflow: auto** and **max-height** on week and day views.

I'm trying to edit **.cal-week-view .cal-time events** (but hour columns doesnt fit horizontally when I add overflow property) and **.cal-day-view .cal-hours-rows** (it seems to ignore max-height attribute for scroll appearing).

Comment: Keep in mind that you can only change these classes in styles.scss if you have default configuration.
Did you try this way? That might be a problem in your case.